How to use @BeforeEach and @AfterEach annotations with MockWebServer?
Doing integration tests, I'm trying to mock the comportement of my controller with one or multiple MockWebServer but doesn't found a solution.
I saw the post here saying that a MockWebServer should only be for a single use.
So I tried a way to use it with @BeforeEach and @AfterEach annotations without success.
I tried this:
@SpringBootTest(
        classes = {
                MyApplication.class,
        },
        properties = {
                "api.url=TEST",
                // ... other properties ...
    })
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
class MyControllerTest {

    private static MockWebServer serverApiA;
    private static MockWebServer serverApiB;
    private static MockWebServer serverApiC;
    private static MockWebServer serverApiD;

    // ... Beans and repos declared here ....

    @BeforeEach
    public void mockHeadersAndStartMockWebServer() throws CustomException, IOException {
        doReturn(new HttpHeaders()).when(SomeServiceImplMock).getHeaders();

        serverApiA = new MockWebServer();
        serverApiA.start();

        HttpUrl httpUrlApiA = serverApiA.url("/operation-a/v1");
        String urlApiA = httpUrlApiA.url().toString();
        System.setProperty("my-project.api.path.url", urlApiA);
    }

    @AfterEach
    void cleanData() throws IOException {
        repositoryA.deleteAll();
        repositoryB.deleteAll();
        repositoryC.deleteAll();
        repositoryD.deleteAll();

        serverApiA.shutdown();
    }

@WithMockUser(value = "somevalue", authorities = "some-authorities")
@Test
void whenCallControllerMethod_withSpecificCase_thenReturnResponseOKAndStatusKO() throws Exception {

        // Given
        // ... Some code to initialise my test ...

        MockResponse mockResponse = getMockResponseApiA(HttpStatus.OK, SomeEnum.VALUE);

        // Mock
        serverApiA.enqueue(mockResponse);

        // When
        MockHttpServletRequestBuilder request = MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/specific/operation")
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .content(createRequestBody());

        MvcResult mvcResult = mockMvc.perform(request)
            .andReturn();

        // Then
        MockHttpServletResponse response = mvcResult.getResponse();
        assertThat(response.getStatus()).isEqualTo(HttpStatus.OK.value());
} 


But I got this Error = java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: [TEST//operation-a/v1] is not a valid HTTP URL.
I also tried the following solutions:

Using dispatcher instead of enqueue, but I couldn't specify multiple "System.setProperty".
Using @BeforeAll and @AfterAll at first like this:

@BeforeEach
public void mockHeaders(){
    doReturn(new HttpHeaders()).when(SomeServiceImplMock).getHeaders();
}

@BeforeAll
public void startMockWebServer() throws CustomException, IOException {
    serverApiA = new MockWebServer();
    serverApiB = new MockWebServer();
    serverApiC = new MockWebServer();
    serverApiD = new MockWebServer();
    
    serverApiA.start();
    serverApiB.start();
    serverApiC.start();
    serverApiD.start();
    
    HttpUrl httpUrlApiA = serverApiA.url("/operation-a/v1");
    String urlApiA = httpUrlApiA.url().toString();
    System.setProperty("my-project.api.pathA.url", urlApiA);
    
    HttpUrl httpUrlApiB = serverApiB.url("/operation-b/v1");
    String urlApiB = httpUrlApiB.url().toString();
    System.setProperty("my-project.api.pathB.url", urlApiB);
    
    HttpUrl httpUrlApiC = serverApiC.url("/operation-c/v1");
    String urlApiC = httpUrlApiC.url().toString();
    System.setProperty("my-project.api.pathC.url", urlApiC);
    
    HttpUrl httpUrlApiD = serverApiD.url("/operation-d/v1");
    String urlApiD = httpUrlApiD.url().toString();
    System.setProperty("my-project.api.pathD.url", urlApiD);
}

@AfterAll
void cleanData() throws IOException {
    repositoryA.deleteAll();
    repositoryB.deleteAll();
    repositoryC.deleteAll();
    repositoryD.deleteAll();

    serverApiA.shutdown();
    serverApiB.shutdown();
    serverApiC.shutdown();
    serverApiD.shutdown();
}

It does worked, but I had to be very carefull of which test to do first. serverApiA.enqueue() is the same stack as serverApiB, serverApiC and serverApiD.
Results where sometimes randoms, different if I launch them in debug or not.
EDIT:
I also have issues while debugging.
If I wait too much in the debugger, some tests run in loops.
If I pass them quickly, they sometimes pass, and sometimes doesn't.
The best solution I have in mind for now is to do each "buggy" test, in his own file. But it's not a good way to do it.

@SpringBootTest(classes = MyApplication.class)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
class MyControllerTest {

    private MockWebServer serverApiA;
    private MockWebServer serverApiB;
    private MockWebServer serverApiC;
    private MockWebServer serverApiD;

    // ... Beans and repos declared here ....

    @BeforeEach
    public void setUp() throws IOException {
        serverApiA = new MockWebServer();
        serverApiA.start();

        serverApiB = new MockWebServer();
        serverApiB.start();

        serverApiC = new MockWebServer();
        serverApiC.start();

        serverApiD = new MockWebServer();
        serverApiD.start();

        // Set the URLs for your APIs
        System.setProperty("my-project.api.pathA.url", serverApiA.url("/operation-a/v1").toString());
        System.setProperty("my-project.api.pathB.url", serverApiB.url("/operation-b/v1").toString());
        System.setProperty("my-project.api.pathC.url", serverApiC.url("/operation-c/v1").toString());
        System.setProperty("my-project.api.pathD.url", serverApiD.url("/operation-d/v1").toString());

        // Mock any headers or behaviors here
        doReturn(new HttpHeaders()).when(SomeServiceImplMock).getHeaders();
    }

    @AfterEach
    void tearDown() throws IOException {
        repositoryA.deleteAll();
        repositoryB.deleteAll();
        repositoryC.deleteAll();
        repositoryD.deleteAll();

        serverApiA.shutdown();
        serverApiB.shutdown();
        serverApiC.shutdown();
        serverApiD.shutdown();
    }

    @WithMockUser(value = "somevalue", authorities = "some-authorities")
    @Test
    void whenCallControllerMethod_withSpecificCase_thenReturnResponseOKAndStatusKO() throws Exception {
        // Given
        // ... Initialize your test data and set up mock responses ...

        // When
        MockHttpServletRequestBuilder request = MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/specific/operation")
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .content(createRequestBody());

        MvcResult mvcResult = mockMvc.perform(request)
                .andReturn();

        // Then
        MockHttpServletResponse response = mvcResult.getResponse();
        assertThat(response.getStatus()).isEqualTo(HttpStatus.OK.value());
    } 
}



I tried it, unfortunately it doesn't change the result.
